# Float value should have 2 decimals

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

I am getting the output as `756.4` but this is equal to `756.40` i know that but still i would like to save it as `756.40` so how can i convert that to the required one

Forgot to mention my `totalamount` is declared as float

`Amount[index]` //In this amount is declared as arraylist

```
totalAmount += float.Parse(Amount[index].ToString());
```

Here after all additons done after the loop i would like to get the required one

A sample code of conversion

```
if (totalAmount.ToString().Contains("."))
        {
            string[] b = totalAmount.ToString().Split('.');
            Dollars = b[0].ToString().PadLeft(10, (char)48);
            cents = b[1].ToString().PadRight(2, (char)48).Substring(0, 2);
        }
        else
        {
            Dollars = totalAmount.ToString().PadLeft(10, (char)48);
            cents = "00";
        }

        FormattedTotalAmounts = Dollars + cents; // Here i am getting the output as i said
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this question is down voted. I guess because it sounded quite demanding.

Comment: Keep in mind that only a string can have a specified number of decimals. A float value is always just a numeric value without any kind of formatting.

Comment: What data type is `Amount[index]`? Converting it to a string and then parsing it again sounds wrong. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: what type is Amount[] or TotalAmount?

Comment: totalamount is declared as float `Amount` as ArrayList

Comment: @user: Then you don't need to do the ToString->Parse thing. It would be much more elegant directly use the float value from the array list: `totalAmount += (float)Amount[index];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code change this

```
if (totalAmount.ToString().Contains("."))
    {
        string[] b = totalAmount.ToString().Split('.');
        Dollars = b[0].ToString().PadLeft(10, (char)48);
        cents = b[1].ToString().PadRight(2, (char)48).Substring(0, 2);
    }
    else
    {
        Dollars = totalAmount.ToString("F2").PadLeft(10, (char)48);//Necessary change
        cents = "00";
    }

    FormattedTotalAmounts = Dollars + cents;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string totalAmountFormatted = totalAmount.ToString("F2");
```

This formats the total amount as a fixed-point number (`F`) with two decimal places (`2`). For details about these *format strings*, see the following two MSDN articles:

- [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: @user: This example assumes totalAmount to be of a numeric data type, such as float. (As others have already pointed out, decimal is a more suitable data type for monetary values, since it avoids the floating-point precision problems.)

Comment: thanks a lot, works very well, just I put in my value only "F2" (ex: `xx.ToString("F2")`) .

Answer (score 1):

```
String.Format("{0:0.00}", 756.4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
decimal t = 756.40m;
MessageBox.Show(t.ToString("0.00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should probably be using `Decimal` if this is financial data.

Second, numeric values don't have trailing spaces, strings do.

EDIT: C# 2.0 tag added - LINQ removed.

```
Decimal total;
foreach (object oAmount in Amount)
{
   Decimal amount = (Decimal)oAmount;
   total += amount;
}
String FormattedTotalAmounts = total.ToString("G");
```

passing "F" to ToString will work equally well.

EDIT responding to comment.

```
   String FormattedTotalAmounts = total.ToString("0000000000.00");
```

gives 10 0's on the left and 2 0's on the right.

Comment: If i would like to convert the string value as per i said then how can i

Answer (score 0):

you can use numberformat in your ToString like

```
SomeVar.ToString("#,##0.00")
```